# Prove the Schwarz space is contained in $C_0(R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, schwartz-space

In our definition,

$$C_0(R^n) =\left\{f\in C(\mathbb R^n):\ \lim_{x\to\infty} |f(x)| = 0\right\}.$$

I try to prove the [Schwarz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) is contained in $C_0(R^n)$, but I have no idea how to prove that the Schwarz space satisfies the second condition in $C_0(\mathbb R^n)$. Can someone give me an answer? I will be so grateful.

Appreciate a lot in advance.

Comment: When $\beta = 0$, one consequence is that $|x f(x)|\le C$ for some $C$ .

Comment: And probably you should learn to use latex now.  It's not that difficult (See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference))

Comment: @JohnMa Yes I follow your hint. Thank you for editing my problem the second time, and I have saw the link you post here. It’s really not difficult, I will try to type in LeTex next time. Thank you again John :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sup_{x\in\Bbb R^n}\left|x^\alpha \partial_\beta f(x)\right|<\infty\;\;\;\forall\,\alpha\in\Bbb N_0\implies \sup_{x\in\Bbb R^n}\left|xf(x)\right|=M<\infty$$

choosing $\;\beta=0\;$

Comment: I see. If f doesn’t tend to zero when |x| tends to infinity, then sup|xf(x)| will be infinity. Thank you Don. :)